# SQL - Creating a trigger for view tables

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger for a table, I've done this for a few other tables without issues before but somehow with this table I get an error. I assume because it's a view table the error occurs. I have to do this for a few more view tables and I cannot seem to figure out how to get it done. I would appreciate some tips on how to properly use INSTEAD into my code. I've read through quite a bit of similar posts but I guess my skills just fall short for this one.

```
create Trigger DVLP_T_InsertBillNoItemsalesdel On VwICBill_8 
For UpDate
As
If UpDate(FStatus)
Begin
    If Not Exists(Select 1 
                  From inserted a
                  Inner Join t_Item b on b.FItemClassID=3026 AND b.FNumber=a.FBillNo)
    Begin
        INSERT INTO t_Item (FItemClassID,FParentID,FLevel,FName,FNumber,FShortNumber,FFullNumber,FFullName,FDetail,FDeleted) 
        Select 3026,0,1,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,FBillNo,1,0
        From inserted

        INSERT INTO t_Log (FDate,FUserID,FFunctionID,FStatement,FDescription,FMachineName,FIPAddress) 
        Select getdate(),16394,'A00701',5,'新建核算项目:'+FBillNo+' 核算项目类别:销售订单号','',''
        From inserted

        Insert Into t_BaseProperty(FTypeID,FItemID,FCreateDate,FCreateUser,FLastModDate,FLastModUser,FDeleteDate,FDeleteUser)
        Select 3, b.FItemID, getdate(), 'administrator', Null, Null, Null, Null
        From inserted a
        Inner Join t_Item b on b.FItemClassID=3026 And a.FBillNo=b.FNumber

    End
End
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 8197, Level 16, State 6, Procedure DVLP_T_InsertBillNoItemsalesdel, Line 1
>   The object 'VwICBill_8' does not exist or is invalid for this operation.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: So according to the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "You can't define AFTER triggers on views." (AFTER=FOR).

Comment: Your question is very confusing the way you call a view a table... they aren't the same thing.

Comment: In simple terms, with an `instead of` trigger, you have to carry out any data insert/update/delete that you want to happen. There are loads of tutorials out there showing how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of DML triggers the FOR (or AFTER) trigger and the INSTEAD OF trigger, but the only one you can use with views are INSTEAD OF triggers. In contrary to the AFTER type which fires after an event, the INSTEAD OF trigger executes instead of the firing statement. In other words, this type of triggers replaces the firing statement.

Read this article for detailed explanation: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5984/sql-server-trigger-on-view-example/